# Passing data from android to phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an Android application using PhoneGap.

My application is launched with a custom URI with something like myscheme://mydata.
I can get the data in my activity class as follows.

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW))
    {
        Uri data = intent.getData();

        if (data != null)
        data.toString();
    }
```

However I couldn't find any way to pass this data onto my javascript code on phonegap side.
Any help is appreciated,
Regards

Comment: You may need to create a custom PhoneGap plugin for this.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at the WebIntent plugin - https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/WebIntent in the PhoneGap Plugins repo https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking window.Invoke_params in your javascript?

The following link seems to indicate that it should work on iOS at least
http://remysharp.com/2010/09/01/custom-url-schemes-in-phonegap/

Answer (score 0):

For passing a data from android to javascript using phonegap
You can try to make a plugin 
and via `exceute()` method you can pass the data.